# Filtering of online/dynamic/live/active/incoming/real-time/streaming data - Savitzky-Golay, Kalman, Others?

Tags: python, signal-processing, smoothing, kalman-filter, real-time-data

I've been implementing a real-time filtering/smoothing of incoming data using Savitzky-Golay (specifically, 'savgol_filter(values, window_size, order)' from scipy). Basically, at each timestep, new data comes in and is appended to data_list. I then apply savgol_filter to data_list, and keep the last value in the filtered_data_list as my final value for this timestep.

This works, but introduces a delay equal to N = (window_size - 1) / 2. You can clearly see this in the image below (grey = original data (at 10Hz); red = savgol applied to entire dataset afterwards; blue = real-time savgol applied to incoming data):

[image]

This is probably because Savitzky-Golay calculates the filtered value for the middle of a window of size window_size. So at each timestep, it uses window_size/2 values from the past and window_size/2 from the future. The integrated mode='interp' parameter for savgol_filter doesn't seem to solve this. Using mode='nearest' or other modes results in way worse output signals.

So I have multiple questions related to this:

1. Can savgol_filter be tweaked in a way to only use values from the past? Will this solve the delay issue?
2. If not, can anyone recommend other types of filters that would do the trick? Ideally a 'one-sided' FIR filter that only uses past values and doesn't generate a delay. I've heard a lot of good of Kalman filters, but they seem extremely complex to use.
3. Are there good practices to be aware of surrounding filtering and/or smoothing of incoming data?

Anyway if anyone could help me eliminate or reduce the delay in my filtered data, maybe in some totally different way, I'd be incredibly grateful.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Applying weights (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) to the data could help resolve this 'delay'.

Comment: To decrease delay (not remove it) use IIR filter?

Answer (score 0):

Many filters use past informations to predict the present.

A trick in your case would be to add zeros numbers/arrays to feed your filter. This should remove the delay.